# Error while checking in publishing page SP 2013 on premise

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, check-in

**Problem**: I have a large intranet portal, in one of the sub site after opening a page in an Edit mode and then try to check it in from ribbon, I get traditional SP error screen with a co-relation id.

**My Investigation**:
After getting details from the log file for relevant co-relation id following error message I get.

> ***this may be because the checked out user is accessing the page, or it could be that sharepoint user account has item checked out***

**Types of check ins working fine**:

- Remaining on same window, if I refresh, then page opens up in non-edit mode. If I try to check in, then it works fine
- From the pages library if I try to check in a page it works fine.
- In other sub sites pages with same page layout have no problem.

Comment: As you are using the Publishing portal, did you configure the Object Cache(super user and super reader)?

Comment: Yes I am using publishing portal, and have not configured Object Cache(super user and super reader). This issue started occurring in last 2 days other wise it was all fine..

Comment: in the uls logs, did it talk about the object cache?

Comment: Yes in few of the lines cache was mentioned, like publishing cache and a function having cache in name of it's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error typically occured when Object Cache not properly configured on the web app level. Please configure the Object cache(super user and super reader account), this required IIS reset so plan it accordingly.

1. Add Users in the Policy of Web App.
2. Now run the below Powershell:

   ```
   $wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "<WebApplication>"

   $wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"] = "<SuperUser>"

   $wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"] = "<SuperReader>"

   $wa.Update()
   ```
3. IISreset on all server in farm.

[Configure object cache user accounts in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Hi This partially solves my problem, running this script solved once, but I guess for some other reasons same error occurred. I will have deeper look into it and update..